# How do i remove from my List<string> links of websites that are external?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
private void ToLocalSiteOnlyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (buttonSwitch == true)
            {
                ToLocalSiteOnlyToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                buttonSwitch = false;
                removeExt = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ToLocalSiteOnlyToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                buttonSwitch = true;
                removeExt = false;
            }
        }



private void removeExternals(List<string> externals)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < externals.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!externals[i].StartsWith(mainUrl))
            {
                externals.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i click the menu and its red then im calling the function removeExternals in here:

```
private List<string> test(string url, int levels,DoWorkEventArgs eve)
        {

            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
            List<string> webSites;
            try
            {
                doc = hw.Load(url);
                webSites = getLinks(doc);
                removeDupes(webSites);
                if (removeExt == true)
                {
                    removeExternals(webSites);
                }
```

Now the webSites List contain links of sites like for example:

```
www.ynet.co.il
www.hot.co.il
www.walla.co.il
```

Now the variable mainUrl is http://www.ynet.co.il
I want each iertion im calling the test function and then webSites each time have a different List of links to remove all the links that not start with http://www.ynet.co.il

So in the end each time i will come up in webSites with links that only start with: http://www.ynet.co.il

But it seems that my removeExternals function does not working good as i wanted.

Where is the problem and how to repair it ? Thanks.

Comment: why not use some linq, externals.Where(s => !s.StartsWith(mainUrl)); should work I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your loop:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < externals.Count; i++)
  {
      if (!externals[i].StartsWith(mainUrl))
      {
          externals.RemoveAt(i);
      }
  }
```

Every time you call `RemoveAt()`, you're changing all the indexes.  If you call `RemoveAt(1)`, then everything after 1 is shifted down.  I'd recommend looping through in reverse order, like:

```
  for (int i = externals.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
      if (!externals[i].StartsWith(mainUrl))
      {
          externals.RemoveAt(i);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Mike Christensen about the reason of your problem. This is, what I'd recommend instead of looping:

```
externals.RemoveAll(s => s.StartsWith(mainUrl));
```

You could replace your `removeExternals` method with this line.

Comment: `+1`, a fine approach as well!

Comment: Konstantin tried your approach too also working great. Just needed to add ! before the s.StartsWith

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is your  removeExternals method is deleting items from the zero element out, which can lead to incorrect deletions because the numbered elements change with the indexed deletions. To solve that problem, reverse your loop to go from the end to the beginning, which will guarantee the deletions are done in the right order.